# Why don't functional sequences work with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, magrittr

I would like to extract some plotting code using a functional sequence as described in http://www.r-bloggers.com/magrittr-1-5/. However, it does not work

```
require(magrittr); require(ggplot2); require(dplyr)

plot_me <- . %>% (ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point())
iris %>% plot_me
```

When trying this, R gives the following error

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Doing the same using simple piping works nicely:

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

What's wrong with my functional sequence/code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't really explain why, but the following works.

(It might be because of the use of `{` instead of `(` to control the order of computation inside the pipe).

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_me <- . %>% {ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()}
iris %>% plot_me
```

[image]